# Why do WhatsApp is not working properly after upgrading my Lumia 525 to Windows 8.1?

Tags: 8.1, whatsapp, nokia-lumia-525

Before upgrading my Lumia 525 to Windows 8.1, WhatsApp worked very well, which means all the new notifications had received properly but after upgrading to 8.1 I’m not getting new WhatsApp notifications in the Tile or Notification section. I can get those messages after opening WhatsApp. I remembered one thing while upgrading 8.1 that Phone warned me that WhatsApp won’t work properly in this version. Is it possible to rectify this issue? Do anyone facing the same issue?

Comment: If you send an email to them they will say that this version is not supported. I tried. But actually mine works.

Answer (score 3):

Couple of things to try before you reinstall whatsapp.

1. Check Battery Saver and verify Whatsapp is Allowed to run in background.
2. Restarting the phone once to see if it solves the problem.

If not, try reinstalling Whatsapp once. Dont forget to take a backup of messages in Whatsapp -> settings

Comment: I had to re-install it.

Answer (score 2):

Try to re-install it.. It worked fine on mine... Delete -> Reboot -> Fresh Install .. Remeber its Windows ;)

EDIT (more details):

With a delete and a fresh re-install you also delete the settings and other artefacts/logs (stuff from previous versions) that are created other the time and gives you now these errors. with the reboot you make sure that these Data is removed and isn't used from the new fresh installed Whatsapp.

Answer (score -4):

i had the problem and manual backup solves it

Comment: Can you elaborate on this solution a bit? Right now this is more of a comment than a full answer.

Comment: Downvote until you elaborate more your answer.